# Select a spreadsheet more intelligently using Google Sheets API?

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-api, google-sheets

I have been looking in to the sheets API so that I can update the values within a certain spreadsheet, however I can't find an intelligent way to select it, rather just entries like below:

```
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);
//selects spreadsheet
SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = (SpreadsheetEntry)feed.Entries[0];
Console.WriteLine(spreadsheet.Title.Text);
```

At the moment it selects the last edited by `(SpreadsheetEntry).feed.Entries[0]`
and if I wanted the second edited it would be `(SpreadsheetEntry).feed.Entries[1]` and so fourth.

What I'd like to achieve: `(SpreadsheetEntry).feed.Entries["My Spreadsheet 1"]` something along those lines. Rather having to loop through all spreadsheets and then matching up a name as that is just to long winded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by selecting your spreadsheet when you make SpreadsheetQuery:

```
SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
query.Title = "My Spreadsheet 1";
```